# How to I wire this particular variant of 2.5mm female jack?

Tags: audio, pins, pinout

[image: Topside]

[image: Underside having pins]

The second image has the pins not the top one.
Now the pinouts are a bit confusing here. Now, I've wired a jack before but none like this. Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you insert a plug into the jack, some of the pieces of metal inside will move along the outside of the plug, and some will remain stationary. The pieces that move are the ones you need to solder the signal to, and the others are connections to the moving pieces when there is no plug in place. The specific application will dictate whether or not the stationary pieces should be soldered to.

Comment: Ideally there should've been 3 plugs if I'm not wrong. There are 5 pins on this one!! Confusing!

Comment: One is the ground connection. Two are the signal connections. The other two are NC throws for the signal connections.

Comment: What do you mean by NC throws? (Do you mean No Connection required there?) Thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: Normally Closed, as a switch or relay may have.

Comment: Since I have a mic in my headphone how do I apply DC bias to it through this connector? I do want to use the mic only in this case.